# How to update workitem for a field with no data in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client to fix some stuff.
 The request is: I have workitem with a field which has no data, now I need to update the workitem for that field, how can I make it?

```
    public void UpdateWorkItem(int workItemId, Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        if (workItemId <= 0) return;

        var workItem = tfsStore.GetWorkItem(workItemId);

        //now if I use workItem.Fields["updatingKey"] it'll throw exception since the field updatingKey does not exist in the Fields of the workitem.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the Work Item you are going to modify, just change the value of the specific field you need to change:

```
workitem.Fields["Custom Field"].Value = "New Value";
```

Detail code snippet please take a look at this similar question:  [How to update a custom TFS field programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922872/how-to-update-a-custom-tfs-field-programmatically)